# URL Redirection in sinatra not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

Please find my code which I use to re-direct, in case the authentication is correct/true.

```
post '/user/validate' do
  login = params[:login]
  pwd = params[:pwd]
  if User.authenticate(login, pwd).nil?
    @error = "Username and the password do not match"
    puts "There is an error in authentication"
    halt erb :login
  else
    redirect to('https://www.google.com')
  end  
end
```

this doeson' t work. Althought the web console shows that a GET request is being triggered to my directed URL google. The address bar in the browser doesn't load the new page, it continues to show the template/view of the previous request.

Hi, Please see below the ***Javascript*** code for an ajax Call, using this the redirect doesnt work but using the plain old form submit-page thing the redirect works.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#send").click(function(event)
 {
    var data = { "login": $("#login").val(), "pwd": $("#pwd").val() };
    $.post( '/user/validate', data, 'json');
 });
});
```

Plain ***form*** tag

```
<form method="post" action="/user/validate">
<input type="submit" value="Signup" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `redirect ('https://www.google.com/')`

Comment: Yes, neither that works.  I have looked deeper into the situation and realised that GET->GET redirect's work using the redirect helper method but POST->GET and GET->POST don't seem to work. Any ideas to implement this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for giving this detail later but I am making a POST query using ajax ( jquery ) in a form submission that I have written. When I remove this jquery and simply use the <input type= submit> to complete form submission it works. So basically the question is how to run this with ajax, form submission

Comment: Can you show your js code? I have a idea what it could be.

Comment: @Sir l33tname  I hope the edit helps out

Comment: Does redirecting to another page in your app work? Looks like you could be coming up against the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question first:

> URL Redirection in sinatra not working?
>   URL Redirection works fine with sinatra.

**The Problem**
Your problem is that you post json data with jquery. Then the difference between your javascript solution and the form solution is that a form create form data.

**Example**
To see the difference a curl example:

Form data

> curl -X POST 127.1:4567/ -d "foo=bar"

Normal post data

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"payload":"xyz"}' 127.1:4567/

As you can see these are not the same. The problem is now that by default sinatra only parse form data.

**Quickfix: request.body**
If you need these just at on position you can parse the params manually from:

> request.body.read

**Solution: rake-contrib**
Or better use rake-contrib.

1. Install it with `gem install rake-contrib`
2. require it

   > require 'rack'
   >
   > require 'rack/contrib'
3. load it `use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser`

With these rake take care of parsing your post data in params.